# Gerrit change-merged Hook

Tags: git, githooks, gerrit

I use git as my version control system and have set up a Gerrit site to do the code review. I would like to create a hook to do the following:

- When the admin clicks the Submit button, a file (called **version.txt**)
  should be modified.
- Script should open the file.
- Find the following text (where the ID may change)

  `#version Change-Id: Ie1411d50f6beb885bc3d3b7d8c587635e1446c18`
- Replace the Change-Id with the Change-Id of the new patch.
- So, if the patch being merged has the `Change-Id:    I1c25f7b967084008b69a6a8aefa6e3bb32967b82` then the **version.txt** file
  should contain the following string after the script is run:

  `#version Change-Id: I1c25f7b967084008b69a6a8aefa6e3bb32967b82`
- Then the hook should create a new commit (since now there has been a change in one of the files) and push this last commit to master.

I feel this would be possible using a **change-merged** hook. Am I right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# See link below for actual command line format
# you may need to make the argument parsing more robust
CHANGE_ID=$2

git clone ${GIT_DIR} /tmp/repo-${CHANGE_ID}
echo "#version Change-Id: ${CHANGE_ID}" > /tmp/repo-${CHANGE_ID}/version.txt
GIT_DIR=/tmp/repo-${CHANGE_ID}/
cd /tmp/repo-${CHANGE_ID}/
git add /tmp/repo-${CHANGE_ID}/version.txt
git commit -m'Auto-updated version'
git push origin master
rm -rf /tmp/repo-${CHANGE_ID}/
```

http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.2.2/config-hooks.html#_change_merged

On principle, I'm not a fan of this approach, and I think it should be better done on the way out (e.g., a "install.sh" script, which can use git commands to extract the revision hash, and generate a version.txt file from there).  But something like this should put you in the right direction.  This is untested, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll give it a try and report back. Can you elaborate a bit about the 'install.sh' script?

Comment: Now I see the problem: change-merged hook doesn't take the commit message as argument. So, it wouldn't be possible to keep the commit message when the patch is finally pushed to the branch. Hmmm...

Comment: Oh you want to *modify* the original commit?  If all you want to do is amend the commit, you can do that (`git commit --amend -C HEAD`) in place of the `git commit -m..` line above.  The `-C HEAD` means "use the commit message and author from the HEAD revision, and don't open an editor to prompt for the message."

Comment: Updated link: https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/hooks/+/refs/heads/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/hooks.md#change_merged

Answer (score 0):

Better to do it the other way around -

Instead of doing an "un-verified" change to a commit, behind Gerrit's back,
put a **git-tag** on that commit.

For more details, see *[Git - Tagging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)*