# How to catch changes in Gerrit Repo from Jenkins and build the project on change?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have setup project to build Gerrit based android ICS source from Jenkins using Gerrit Repo. It builds source successfully.
Now, i want to make some changes in my Android source on any branch of Gerrit. How can I detect those changes from jenkins and trigger a build for every changes i merged in gerrit based android source automatically without any manual intervention ?
Is Gerrit Trigger plugin useful for it ?, I have setup Gerrit Trigger in Jenkins Test connection works fine but when i made some changes in source the build is not triggered ?
Please, give the solution for it or any other option to catch changes and building source from jenkins ?
Thanks,
amar.

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure if i understand the question, but if you just want the build to to pickup changes made to a git repo, just configure a post-commit hook or poll the repo for chagnges in intervalls.

If you mean like changeing something in the gerrit to make a new commit, this can be what you looking for: [Gerrit change-merged Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336804/gerrit-change-merged-hook)